# Squeezing $e^{-ax}\ln(\tan^{-1}(abx))$ with $g(y) = -\ln|y|$

Tags: functions, inequality

I am trying to find the constants $a,b$  such that
$$f(x) = e^{-ax}\ln(\tan^{-1}(abx))$$is squeezed by
$$g(y) = -\ln|y|$$
As $x\in(0,\infty)$ without plotting the two functions.

I have tried to solve for :
$$e^{-x}≥e^{-ax}\ln(\tan^{-1}(abx))$$
$$1≥e^{x(1-a)}\ln(\tan^{-1}(abx)) $$
I could arbitrarily set $a=1$ and solve for $1≥\ln(\tan^{-1}(bx))$ for values of $b$

However this method does not tell me much about $a$ except that it only $1$. I need to analytically find the accepted range of values for $a,b$ that will squeeze $f(x)$

Comment: You can use \ln to get $\ln$ and \tan to get $\tan$. It would look much better.

Comment: What is the link between $y$ and $x$ here?